# Rigorous or not?

Tags: proof-verification, recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients, alternative-proof, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I want to prove
$$T(n,k)=\frac{n}{\left\lfloor\frac{n+k+1}{2}\right\rfloor}(T(n-1,k)+T(n-1,k-1))=\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-k}{\left\lfloor\frac{n-k}{2}\right\rfloor}$$
First we know only that
$$T(n,k)=0, n<k$$
$$T(n,k)=0, n<0, k<0$$
$$T(0,0)=1$$
so obviously
$$T(n,0)=\frac{n}{\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor}T(n-1,0)=\binom{n}{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}$$
next we may notice (for $n\geqslant k$)
$$T(n,k)=\frac{n}{\left\lfloor\frac{n+k+1}{2}\right\rfloor}(\frac{\left\lfloor\frac{n-k+1}{2}\right\rfloor}{n}T(n,k)+\frac{k}{n}T(n,k))$$
then
$$T(n,k)=\frac{n}{k}T(n-1,k-1)=\binom{n}{k}T(n-k,0)=\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-k}{\left\lfloor\frac{n-k}{2}\right\rfloor}$$
which agrees with
$$T(n,k)=\frac{n}{\left\lfloor\frac{n-k+1}{2}\right\rfloor}T(n-1,k)$$
Can we say that all steps looks clear? Is there another way to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see good ideas, but there are also some aspects which have to be considered to make this approach rigorous.

> **What is given/what is to prove?**
>
> The first section introduces a part of a recurrence relation equated with a binomial expression. The weak point here is, it is not clearly stated what is given and what is to prove.
>
> **Proposal:**
>
> Let $n,k$ be non-negative integer. Given a recurrence relation
> \begin{align*}
> T(n,k)&=\frac{n}{\left\lfloor\frac{n+k+1}{2}\right\rfloor}(T(n-1,k)+T(n-1,k-1))\qquad n,k\geq 1\\
> T(0,0)&=1\\
> T(n,0)&=0\qquad n\geq 1\\
> T(0,k)&=0\qquad k\geq 1
> \end{align*}
> the following is valid
> \begin{align*}
> T(n,k)=\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-k}{\left\lfloor\frac{n-k}{2}\right\rfloor}\qquad 0\leq k\leq n\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

Here we clearly state what is given, namely a recurrence relation, and what is to prove, namely the representation of $T(n,k)$ as product of binomial coefficients. Note, that a recurrence relation needs a specification of *all* initial conditions in order to be fully specified.

> **A step in the proof:**
>
> The derivation $T(n,k)=\frac{n}{k}T(n-1,k-1)$ and a possible connection with the representation $T(n,k)=\frac{n}{\left\lfloor\frac{n+k+1}{2}\right\rfloor}(\frac{\left\lfloor\frac{n-k+1}{2}\right\rfloor}{n}T(n,k)+\frac{k}{n}T(n,k))$ is not clear to me. This should be justified.

Comment: Thank you for answer! English not my native, so I don't completely understand it. Also $T(n,0)\ne0$ for $n\geqslant1$. It actually $T(n,0)=\frac{n}{\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor}T(n-1,0)=\binom{n}{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}$. Similar example $\binom{n}{0}=\binom{n-1}{0}$. I agree that step which about you talking is not rigorous, but another tries gives monstrous constructions which (for me) hard to solve.

Comment: Also it OEIS A107230.

Comment: @user514787: You're welcome. The setting of $T(n,0), n\geq 1$ is a *boundary condition* which has to be specified to fully determine the recurrence relation. You are free to specify it according to your needs, for instance: $T(n,0)=\binom{n}{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}, n\geq 1$.

Comment: So, if I understand right, you just only answering to the main question on the title without showing alternative proof?

Comment: @user514787: Correct. The crucial point is, do you want to start from the recurrence relation and derive the binomial expression from it, or do you want to start with the binomial expression and derive the recurrence relation. This has to be clearly specified. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Although there is already a good answer, let me present a different approach.

We can better restate the problem as
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  T(n,k) = 0\quad \left| {\;n < 0\; \vee \;k < 0} \right. \hfill \cr 
  T(n,k) = \binom{n}{k} \binom{n-k}{\left\lfloor {{{n - k} \over 2}} \right\rfloor} =  \hfill \cr 
   =  \left[ {0 = n} \right]\left[ {0 = k} \right] + \left[ {1 \le n} \right]{n \over {\left\lfloor {{{n + k + 1} \over 2}} \right\rfloor }}
 \left( {T(n - 1,k) + T(n - 1,k - 1)} \right) \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
where $[condition]$ denotes the [*Iverson bracket*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)

Let's recall some useful properties of the floor and ceil functions. We have that, for integer $m$
$$
\eqalign{
  & m = \left\lfloor {{m \over 2}} \right\rfloor  + \left\lceil {{m \over 2}} \right\rceil   \cr 
  & \left\lceil {{m \over 2}} \right\rceil  = \left\lfloor {{{m + 1} \over 2}} \right\rfloor  \cr} 
$$

Calling $B(n,k)$ the binomial expression, we can write it as
$$
B(n,k) = \binom{n}{k} \binom{n-k}{\left\lfloor {{{n - k} \over 2}} \right\rfloor}
 = \left[ {0 \le k \le n} \right]{{n!} \over {k!}}{1 \over {\left\lfloor {{{n - k} \over 2}} \right\rfloor !\left\lceil {{{n - k} \over 2}} \right\rceil !}}
$$

Then we have
$$
\eqalign{
  & {{B(n - 1,k)} \over {B(n,k)}} =   \cr 
  &  = \left[ {0 \le k \le n - 1} \right]{{\left( {n - 1} \right)!k!\left\lfloor {{{n - k} \over 2}} \right\rfloor !\left\lceil {{{n - k} \over 2}} \right\rceil !}
 \over {k!\left\lfloor {{{n - 1 - k} \over 2}} \right\rfloor !\left\lceil {{{n - 1 - k} \over 2}} \right\rceil !n!}} =   \cr 
  &  = \left[ {0 \le k \le n - 1} \right]{1 \over n}{{\left\lfloor {{{n + 1 - k} \over 2}} \right\rfloor !} \over {\left\lfloor {{{n - 1 - k} \over 2}} \right\rfloor !}} =   \cr 
  &  = \left[ {0 \le k \le n - 1} \right]{1 \over n}\left\lfloor {{{n + 1 - k} \over 2}} \right\rfloor  \cr} 
$$

and
$$
\eqalign{
  & {{B(n - 1,k - 1)} \over {B(n,k)}} =   \cr 
  &  = \left[ {1 \le k \le n} \right]{{\left( {n - 1} \right)!k!\left\lfloor {{{n - k} \over 2}} \right\rfloor !\left\lceil {{{n - k} \over 2}} \right\rceil !}
 \over {\left( {k - 1} \right)!\left\lfloor {{{n - k} \over 2}} \right\rfloor !\left\lceil {{{n - k} \over 2}} \right\rceil !n!}} =   \cr 
  &  = \left[ {1 \le k \le n} \right]{k \over n} \cr} 
$$

So we conclude that
$$
\eqalign{
  & {{B(n - 1,k) + B(n - 1,k - 1)} \over {B(n,k)}} =   \cr 
  &  = \left[ {0 \le k \le n - 1} \right]{1 \over n}\left\lfloor {{{n + 1 - k} \over 2}} \right\rfloor  + \left[ {1 \le k \le n} \right]{k \over n} =   \cr 
  &  = \left[ {0 \le k} \right]\left[ {1 \le n} \right]\left[ {k\left( { \le n - 1} \right) \le n} \right]{1 \over n}\left\lfloor {{{n + 1 - k} \over 2}} \right\rfloor
  + \left[ {0 \le \left( {1 \le } \right)k} \right]\left[ {1 \le n} \right]\left[ {k \le n} \right]{k \over n} =   \cr 
  &  = \left[ {0 \le k} \right]\left[ {1 \le n} \right]\left[ {k \le n} \right]{1 \over n}\left( {\left\lfloor {{{n + 1 - k} \over 2}} \right\rfloor  + k} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \left[ {0 \le k} \right]\left[ {1 \le n} \right]\left[ {k \le n} \right]\;{{\left\lfloor {{{n + 1 + k} \over 2}} \right\rfloor } \over n} \cr} 
$$

and the thesis is demonstrated.

Comment: Thank you for answer! As Marcus noticed, there are two ways, so you show how exactly solve second. Have you also ideas (or just references for similar problems) how to start from the recurrence relation and derive the binomial expression from it?

Comment: @user514787: I am working on the "direct" way you mention

Comment: Nice to hear that! What can I do for you so?

Comment: @user514787: sorry, but could not find a suitable way to solve the recursion directly (without knowing a priori the expression with the binomials)

Comment: In any case thank you! I saw some of your answers. Part of them really great. So knowing that this question not so easy for you (or somebody with your level) is also helpful.

Comment: @user514787: I saw just now the new version of your post: that's great ! I do not see a better way to achieve it.